# Limit the Output of embedded element in html

Tags: html, css, output, limit

i am not so experienced in html and need some support please.

i've got following code:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="135px" valign="top">
<td>
    <span>{Field1}</span>
    <span>{Field2}</span>
    <span>{Field3}</span>
</td>
<td width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;">
        {FieldSubject}
        <p style="white-space:pre;">{FieldBody}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is all about the line with FieldBody. The demand is just to allow 5 lines of the FieldBody to be shown and right now it looks like:

[image]

And it goes below the border. Is there a way just to output Z1 to Z5 through limitation in html/css etc.?

Comment: Are those Z1, Z2,.. are in separate <p> tags?

Comment: unfortunately not it is all one text/field with line breaks at the end

Comment: Okay, I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you're 'making' your code, programming in some language, that I'm not familiar with (based on the {FieldBody}. If it was me, though - then I would control it, with that programming-language and not in the CSS/HTML. You can do it in the CSS/HTML-though - but it might vary from browser to browser, how good it looks. Here are two suggestions to solutions:

**1) The one I would do, if it was in PHP (or something)**

```
<table style="width:100%;">
 <tr height="135px" valign="top">
  <td>
   <span>{Field1}</span>
   <span>{Field2}</span>
   <span>{Field3}</span>
  </td>
 <td width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;">
  {FieldSubject}

  <?php $z_array = ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z5' ...]
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($z_array as $value) {
  ?>

  <p class="foo-<?php echo $counter ?>">$value</p>

  <?php
  }
  ?>

  <p style="white-space:pre;">{FieldBody}</p>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Above-written code would output it, so instead of this:

```
<p style="white-space:pre;">Z1<br />Z2<br />Z3<br />Z4<br />...</p>
```

Then you would see something along these lines:

```
<p class="foo-1">Z1</p>
<p class="foo-2">Z2</p>
<p class="foo-3">Z3</p>
<p class="foo-4">Z4</p>
<p class="foo-5">Z5</p>
```

This way, then you have `<p>`-tags around all of your Z1, Z2 ... - and then it's easier to control using CSS. In that case, then this line in your CSS-file:

```
.foo-1  {display: none}
```

would hide Z1 from your HTML-file. And `.foo-5 {display:none}` would hide Z5. Above-written code hasn't been tested - and are meant as a proof of concept.

**2) The 'wham-bam-thank-you-mam'-solution (quick'n'dirty!)**

To simply add some styles to your `<p>`.

So instead of this:

```
<p style="white-space:pre;">{FieldBody}</p>
```

Then write this:

```
<p style="display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 20px; white-space:pre;">{FieldBody}</p>
```

And then adjust the height, so you only see the Z's that you want to see. `Display:block;` is there to make the browser handle it as a 'chunk'. `Overflow:hidden;` is there to tell the browser: 'Hey - don't show stuff that's outside the 'chunk', please'. And the `width` and the `height` is there (defined in pixels) to let the browser know, how big the 'chunk' is.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Beatiful :-D Thank you so much the wham-bam-solution not just solved my problem, it also gave me cheers. Indeed the html is embedded in a control which evaluates the html so php was not possible. Also thanks for the explanation it will help me in the future! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If those Z1, Z2,.. are in same p tags, add a line-height to p tag and set max-height to line-height * number of lines to display (for eg., calc(1.2rem * 6) or 7.2rem)

```
td p {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  max-height: calc(1.2rem * 6); 
}
```

If those Z1, Z2,.. are in separate p tags, add the following code to your stylesheet.

```
td p:nth-child(n + 6) { display: none; }
```

It will hide all p tags except first 5.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution made it, but i appreciate your effort to write an answer :-)